# Why in the code I can not use class name as type annotation?

Tags: typescript, types

I installed ts-morph in my project:

```
ts-morph % tree .
.
├── LICENSE
├── dist
│   └── ts-morph.js
├── lib
│   └── ts-morph.d.ts
├── package.json
└── readme.md
```

and in the `lib/ts-morph.ts`, I find the function of class Project:

```
...
getDirectories(): Directory[];
...
```

but when I run to use `getDirectories()` like below will report error:

```
let tsmorph = require('ts-morph')
const { Directory } = tsmorph

const project = new tsmorph.Project();
project.addSourceFilesFromTsConfig('path/to/tsconfig.json')

console.log(Directory) // [class Directory]

const dirs: Directory[] = project.getDirectories() // this line occurs error.

dirs.forEach((item: any) => {
  console.log(item.getPath())
})
```

the error :

```
"Directory" represents a value, but is used here as a type. Does it mean "type Directory"? ts(2749) 
type Directory = /*unresolved*/ any
```

then I change that line to

```
const dirs: typeof Directory[] = project.getDirectories()
```

it works.

but why it use the `typeof Directory` rather than `Directory`?

---

I also test in my demo:
I think it should use `Directory` that's right.

my demo code as below:

```
class Demo {
  age: number = 18;
  getAge: () => {} = () => {
    return this.age  
  }
}

let demos:  Demo[] = [
  new Demo(),
  new Demo(),
  new Demo(),
]

console.log(demos)
```

Answer (score 0):

When you

```js
require('ts-morph')
```

you are importing [ts-morph.js](https://unpkg.com/browse/ts-morph/dist/ts-morph.js). Therefore, in your code,

```js
const { Directory } = tsmorph
```

sets `Directory` to a class, not a type.

Comment: How about `let demos:  Demo[]`? is the `Demo` type rather that class?

Comment: Your demo code is already created within Typescript and the corresponding type has been made for you that just happened to have the same name. That's different from importing a .js file.

Answer (score 0):

Since JS is dynamically typed all objects (string, arrays, etc) are treated as the same at the interpreter level and types are only checked at runtime. From what I understand CommonJS imports (`require` imports) return the module as an object so it might be exporting the `Directory` class as just a JS class declaration without a TypeScript level type, which is just a JS value. So I think the `typeof` operator forces TypeScript to generate a type from the class declaration.

I think importing like this should also import the types:

```
import { Project, Directory } from 'ts-morph';
```

Comment: I don't understand, please explain more.

Comment: I think the Class declaration is being exported as a value with no type and `typeof` infers the type from the Class declaration value. It might not be detecting the type automatically because you're using `require` to import the module

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).